# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /66.201.99.67 (port 80) after 30000ms

Tags: android, webview

While implementing WebView I m facing this error.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /66.201.99.67 (port 80) after 30000ms
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to that IP using the phone's web browser?

Comment: @MichaelDodd no it is working in web browser but phone's internet connection is working.

Comment: Next question is if you can access that IP from a different device or a PC. Might be that the website is down.

Comment: @MichaelDodd in Pc its working.

Comment: post java code..

Comment: And what about other Android devices? Are you connected via Wifi or cellular network? Is your PC connected via WiFi or ethernet?

Comment: @MichaelDodd its working in other devive

Comment: @DivyeshPatel code was working properly before few minutes

Comment: can you post complete error log?

Comment: I personally think it's a network issue rather than a coding issue. Once the address is accessible via the web browser on the phone, this should also work in the app. Deploying the app onto the other working device should show this website loading in the WebView without issue.

Comment: @MichaelDodd is there  any way  to avoid such kind of app crash

Comment: @RituNambath Put a `try catch` around the section of code that loads the page into the webview, and handle anything that drops into the catch clause appropriately.